# How to calculate probability of a cell containing mine in minesweeper?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

In Minesweeper: If we just investigate 1 specific cell and 8 unrevealed cells surrounding it.

I know that the chance of a cell is mine = number of mines (the center number) / number of hidden cells. But what if we have one more cell is revealed? Can someone please show me the way to calculate the probability of the rest of them containing mines?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What is your prior? Is each cell an independent Bernoulli distribution with mine density $p$? Or, like the real game, is there a fixed number of mines $pN$ distributed among a fixed number of squares $N$? It will also matter whether those revealed cells are on the sides of the board. For an example of how to approach the problem, see Siwel's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396494/87023

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325873/123852).

Comment: The bottom problem only has one solution, with one bomb in the top left corner and two bombs in the rightmost column.  The two problems above it are only consistent if there are 3 bombs, but in general, you get different results depending on how many bombs are known to be hidden.